# Exporting multiple featureclasses to shapefiles using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, export, spatial-database, features

I have many feature classes in a geodatabase and I need to save/export them into shapefiles.

Any Ideas?

Click on every single layer -> export is not a good option, due to the number of feature classes in that geodatabase.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

you can use the export (multiple).

In ArcCatalog...
Just right click on the database and choose "export to shapefile (multiple)"

[image: photohere]

If you do it at the database level
you will see everything in the database in the tool listed (there is a remove button if there are a few you don't want).

If you do it at the feature dataset level
you see everything in that fds with the same options to add or remove.

[image]

Just choose the output folder and execute.

Answer (score 2):

In the Python window, enter

```
import arcpy

arcpy.env.workspace = r"copy/and/paste/the/workspace/path/here" 
# The "r" before the '"' allows you to put in normal windows path format (back slashes) by just copying and pasting.

outLocation = "C:/Users/dpdb/Desktop/" # or whatever the destination folder is

inFeatures = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses() """ This will perform this on the listed workspace from above."""

arcpy.FeatureClassToShapefile_conversion (inFeatures, outLocation)
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! Thank-you :) I think it´s helpful to know that you´re able to export just these feature classes you need. Therefore define inFeatures like: inFeatures = ["parcels", "schools"]

Answer (score -1):

Go into ArcMap, make a selection (or def query) if you don't want all of your data exported.  Right click in the TOC, export data -> **Choose a directory and NOT a gdb** and your file will automatically be created as a shapefile.  Feature classes are simply features that reside in a gdb.  Their non-gdb counterparts are automatically shapefiles.

You can do this from ArcCatalog by exporting the feature class to a non-gdb directory too I believe.